# Inserting pandas df into sqlite3 inserts running text, not columns

Tags: python, database, pandas, sqlite

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to insert into a sqlite3 database (writing in python 3.6+).

However, when I insert the data into the table, it shows up as a text file, with text being written continuously. I tried copy/pasting the text from the database file into here on Stackoverflow, but Stackoverflow says there is an error when trying to submit. As an aside data point, when I open Sublime Text and copy/paste the text from the database, the only text that gets pasted is:

> SQLite format 3

So, I am pasting below a screenshot of the text from the database. It looks like Stackoverflow doesn't like those unusual question mark characters.

[image]

My code to pass the pandas dataframe into sqlite3 is as follows. Note that I am only creating the table here (not inserting data yet) and still get this phenotype.

```py
cols = ["name", "website", "phone", "address", "city"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)

conn = sqlite3.connect('TestDB2.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE STUDENTS(
            id integer PRIMARY KEY, 
            name text, 
            age integer,
            city text,
            country text
        )""")
conn.commit()

dfObj.to_sql('STUDENTS', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
```

The pandas dataframe looks nice in python and when writing to an excel file. I am new to the sqlite3 world but am familiar with postgres. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: The repeats of `variable text` is problematic; I haven't tested what that does in Postgres, but either you create about a dozen of identically named columns, or one column whose definition continuously gets overwritten (and you probably end up with just one "variable" column, of type "text").

Comment: The screenshot is very unclear, and overall, [screenshots are strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). If there is private information, please create an example that shows similar behaviour, with just dummy information instead.

Comment: There is no example dataframe, which could have helped. As above, in case of private information, use dummy information with otherwise the same behaviour. See also about creating a [mcve].

Comment: OK, good suggestion. I updated with dummy information. However, I could not copy/paste the text from the database as stackoverflow didn't like the characters. So, I uploaded a more legible screenshot.

Comment: a sqlite3 database is not a text file. The result here is what one gets when opening a sqlite database with a text editor. Use command line `sqlite3` or some tool (my fave [DB browser for sqlite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)) to inspect db contents. It is unclear from the posted code what is `dfObj`. The `to_sql` is meant to insert data.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus, you are precisely right. I did not realize I was looking at the file in a text editor. I installed a plugin for Visual Studio and expected it to provide database visualization. It does not. I installed DB browser and my data is there. Thanks for the recommendation! 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @DinoCoderSaurus mentions:

> a sqlite3 database is not a text file. The result here is what one gets when opening a sqlite database with a text editor. Use command line `sqlite3` or some tool (my fave [DB browser for sqlite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)) to inspect db contents. It is unclear from the posted code what is `dfObj`. The `to_sql` is meant to insert data.

I did not realize I was looking at the file in a text editor. I installed a plugin for Visual Studio and expected it to provide database visualization. It does not. I installed DB browser and my data is there.